# Question mark(?) after data type

Tags: variables, swift

These two statements make me confused

```
var optionalString: String? = "Hello"
```

Instead we could write it

```
var optionalString: String = "Hello"
```

What's the difference between these two?

We can also do this without optional values.

```
var str: String = nil
str = "Hello"
```

Please clarify.

Comment: People who doesn't know about `Swift`, don't do downvotting....

Comment: @rickster It's not duplicate with that question, little bit different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The question mark signifies that it may contain either a value, or no value at all. Without it, it cannot ever be `nil`.

```
var str: String = "Hello"
str = nil // Error
```

Answer (score 6):

The Question Mark (?) marks **optional values**. In Swift only optional values allowed to potentially be `nil`.

The advantage of this feature is that it isn't necessary to check against `nil` for all non optional values.

Answer (score 2):

Question mark (?) is way to mark a value optional,

```
var optionalString: String? = "Hello"
```

Mean optionalString could contain a value or it could be nil.

Following is from Swift programming language book.

> In an if statement, the conditional must be a Boolean expression
>
> You can use if and let together to work with values that might be
>   missing. These values are represented as optionals. An optional value
>   either contains a value or contains nil to indicate that the value is
>   missing. Write a question mark (?) after the type of a value to mark
>   the value as optional.